# Quickest way to merge or tile many thousands of rasters with empty space between them

Tags: raster, gdal, tiles, raster-conversion

I have many thousands of images (actually millions, but one step at a time) that are jpgs with associated world files. They were taken with a downward facing camera as a vehicle traversed terrain on a path, but the paths were only rarely close enough to form overlaps between tracks. Therefore the photos describe tracks across the terrain, with plenty of overlaps between images on the same tracks, and some overlaps between tracks, but in between is a great deal of empty space. The empty space is probably 99% or more.

I want a good way to explore this data, and at the moment am trying to create tiles. My workflow so far is:

jpg => vrt with `gdal.Warp` => merged vrt with `gdal_merge` => tiles with `gdal2tiles`

The first two steps are quite fast. However, the last tiling stage is proving to be prohibitively slow even with a subset of 2000 images and using all 20 cores on my machine, and using -x to ignore empty tiles. I can see the tiles being made, it is working, but I can't imagine using this for the entire dataset. I want to avoid making one large tiff that covers the entire area as this would be extremely large.

Is there a faster way to create these tiles or should I be considering other options like a raster database? It needs to handle thousands to millions of rasters.

Edit: I will look into the geotiff creation options like `SPARSE_OK`. I have also found this proprietary driver that seems promising [MRR](https://customer.precisely.com/s/article/MRR-Multi-Resolution-Raster-Revolutionizing-Raster?language=en_US#:%7E:text=An%20MRR%20is%20a%20sparse,only%20sparsely%20populated%20with%20data.)

> For example, some rasters can be extremely large but only sparsely
> populated with data. This model is far better suited to modern
> surveying techniques - like LIDAR - which may collect data over a
> highly irregular coverage polygon. One possible example of such a
> dataset is a LIDAR survey which is designed to survey a highway. Such
> a survey may be orders of magnitude longer than it is wide. In cases
> such as these, the MRR format does not store data in the empty
> regions, but still remains flexible enough to add additional data to
> the source file any time. This allows extremely sparse datasets to be
> stored efficiently on disk, be rapidly accessed and easily updated.

Comment: why are you regenerating tiles at the end? just use a server that can take a big input raster and generate tiles (if you need them) as you pan the viewer. I'd suggest a compressed tiled geotif (it can use JPG internally) - then if you need look into mosaicing and pyramiding

Comment: I want to avoid making an overall geotiff because it will be very large. For example, I am currently making one with the subset of 2000 files, it is 38% done and the tiff is already 85.3 GB in size. This subset is a tiny quadrant of the full dataset. A postage stamp in comparison. I thought tiles would be a better idea because the full dataset is only ever rendered at a much lower resolution, but still allows you to zoom in and see the detail where you need to.

Comment: To add to the above, the geotiff contains "data" for the 99% of the image that is actually blank in my case, but blank tiles are never produced (with the -x option).

Comment: Then you need to turn on compression and tiling, I've had entire countries in 10gb

Comment: Compression and tiling helped a bit but the biggest thing was turning on SPARSE_OK, this allows empty tiles in the tif to have no bytes. So my empty regions don't contribute to the tif. The 200GB tif is now just 4 GB. However, this is not a solution because it still took about 7 hours to produce, which is far too long.